# Jquery next adjacent selector with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could i use the adjacent selector "+" with the $(this).

I would need a help with the commented lines with //this doesnt work:

```
$(".ExpandCollapse").click(function () {
            if ($(this).nextUntil('.Collapsable').is(':visible'))
            {
                //this doesnt work 
                $(this + ".Collapsable").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                //this doesnt work
                $(this + ".Collapsable").show();
            }
        });
```

Could you give me a hand?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next(".Collapsable").hide();
```

Or simply:

```
$(this).next().hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also cut down on having two statements for hiding and showing:

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the `DOM element` of invocation. You can't concat a `string` to that.

So you either can directly use `this` to act on it

```
$(this).hide();
```

or you can walk through the `DOM` from there

```
$(this).next().hide();
$(this).prev().hide();
$(this).closest('.Collapsable').hide();
// another 200 methods
```