# jQuery next() with $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a form with repeating sets of elements.

When a select with class `credit_req_select` changes I want to show/hide and possibly clear **only** the **next** text input with class `credit_line_text`.

The change() func below is not finding the textfields and I think it must have to do with how I am using `$(this)`.

What is the correct way to grab these textfields?

My HTML is

```
<p class="file_info">*Credit Required: 
    <select name='default_credit_requirements' id='default_credit_requirements' class="credit_req_select">
<option></option>
<option value='1' selected>Do not include</option>
<option value='2' >Include if able</option>
<option value='3' >Must include</option>
</select>
    </p>
    <p class="file_info">
      <label>*Credit Line:
        <input  type="text" name="default_credit_line" id="default_credit_line" class="credit_line_text" value="" />
      </label>
    </p>
```

My function looks like this, same as the answer here [Jquery next adjacent selector with $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413435/jquery-next-adjacent-selector-with-this)

```
$('.credit_req_select').change(function() {
    if(this.value > 1) {    
        $(this).next(".credit_line_text").show();
        console.log($(this).next(".credit_line_text").attr('id'));
    } else {
        $(this).next(".credit_line_text").val('');
        $(this).next(".credit_line_text").hide();   
    }
});
```

I have also tried this answer [jquery next() returning nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899806/jquery-next-returning-nothing)

```
$('.credit_req_select').change(function() {
    if(this.value > 1) {    
        $(this).nextUntil(".credit_line_text").show();
        console.log($(this).nextUntil(".credit_line_text").attr('id'));
    } else {
        $(this).nextUntil(".credit_line_text").val('');
        $(this).nextUntil(".credit_line_text").hide();  
    }
});
```

Also tried assigning this to a var per [jQuery $(this).next() not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436093/jquery-this-next-not-working-as-expected?rq=1)

Comment: .next only looks at the immediately next sibling. In your case, you're working with 2nd cousins.

Comment: The [`.next()` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selects only the _immediately following sibling element_ if it matches the selector you provide, or it selects nothing if the next element doesn't match. `.next()` does _not_ search down through the DOM looking for a matching element. The `.nextUntil()` method has more of a search vibe about it, but still it deals only with following _siblings._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$(this).closest('p.file_info').next().find(".credit_line_text")
```

As your input is already having an id `default_credit_line` and as Id's are supposed to be unique, you can use this.

```
$('#default_credit_line').val("");
```

Comment: He should probably take that ID off. I don't think he's keeping them unique.

Comment: I most certainly am keeping them unique.  The subsequent fields are created via a loop in PHP and have these attributes `name="credit_line<?=$i?>" id="credit_line<?=$i?>" class="required credit_line_text"`

Answer (score 0):

What you should really do is wrap each `repeating set of elements` in something. For example a `div` with the class `element`. Then your select query will be much easier to read.

```
$(this).closest('.element').find(".credit_line_text")
```